# any workaround for an Apps using the FB to access an Apps user's friend's friends profile photo and name

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile

Developing iOS-based mobile Apps using the FaceBook. But the FB does not support friends_* permissions with API v2.0 any longer to access an Apps user's friend's friends profile photo and name. Looking for any other way that makes the Apps to access them after an Apps user log-ins the FB thru the Apps.

Comment: You can only get friends of the current user, that are users of your app as well, and have granted `user_friends` permission too. That is a deliberate restriction introduced by Facebook, and you have to respect it. Should anyone suggest any “workarounds”, be aware that those are not allowed. Your app has to make do with the friends that are using your app as well – just like any other app.

Answer (score 0):

As far i know you have to submit facebook app for review in order to acces user's frindlist. Without review you can only fetch friends who installed the app

Comment: No. `user_friends` permission does not need review. And you can only get friends that are using the app as well, that has nothing to do with review.

Comment: so it's not possible anymore to fetch the whole friend list?

Comment: No, it is not. That change was made with the introduction of API v2.0 already, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Sorry for my mistaken answer! (and for the bad english :P)